# <button> is not inheriting css properties properly

Tags: html, css

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: fantasy
}
.form {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.form * {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="form">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Username</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="username" value={{username}}>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="label">Email (optional)</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email" value={{email}}>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <button type="submit">Create Account!</button>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</form>
```

When I run it in Chrome, the button element seems to completely disregard the css and appear at the left end of the screen, that too *above* the rest of the table rows (when it should in fact be below!).

I tried to replace it with an `<input type="submit">` tag, but it shows the same problem.

Any ideas why this button element is misbehaving?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: This question is [off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Why use tables?? You have 2 inputs with labels and a button; no need to wrap these in a table.

Comment: @frenchie I thought it looked neater that way. Saw it being used by an instructor in an online course...

Comment: @zeo: no terrible usage of tables. Search online about using tables for layout: it's old, from the early days... Use divs instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. You are trying to put a button as a child element of a table row, but only table cells may be children of table rows.

Add a TD.

Better yet, [stop using tables for layout](https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html).

Use apropriate markup, including [labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/) and apply your [layout with CSS](https://www.sitepoint.com/style-web-forms-css/).

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: fantasy
}
.form {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.form * {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="form">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Username</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="username" value={{username}}>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="label">Email (optional)</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email" value={{email}}>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><button type="submit">Create Account!</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to conclude button into `td`:

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="form">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Username</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="username" value={{username}}>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="label">Email (optional)</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email" value={{email}}>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td colspan=2>
        <button type="submit">Create Account!</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</form>
```